# Validating user input in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, validation

Hey guys I am doing a project for school and am having a little trouble, I have a variable "reservationNumber" and im attempting to check if the number the user inputs is in the array, if not it returns a string saying the number was not found. It is working fine and displays the correct info when there is a valid input but when an invalid input is detected it gives a null.pointer.exception error. I tried writing it so that if the number is not detected the private method returns -1, then when I call the tickerInformation method, if that the variable 'ticket' returns -1 then it returns "invalid reservation number". This is where is error is being raised and only occurs when I enter an invalid number please help.

```
public void ticketInformation(String reservationNumber)
{
      int ticket = searchArray(reservationNumber); 

      if (ticket == -1)
      {
         System.out.println("The reservation number entered was n0t found");
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.print("\n" + ticketSale[ticket].toString());
      }
}

private int searchArray(String reservationNumber)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ticketSale.length; i++)
    {
        if (ticketSale[i].getReservationNumber().equals(reservationNumber))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: "but when an invalid input is detected it gives a null.pointer.exception error" - On which line?

Answer (score 0):

ticketSale[i].getReservationNumber().equals(reservationNumber) has an issue. Share the declaration and init for array "ticketSale". If ticketSale array is for abstract data type then why equal is called with String?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the whole code but I think that when you enter invalid number as reservation number, it does not assigned to the related object's instance variable. So `getReservationNumber()` might be returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Add a null check,

```
private int searchTicketSales(String reservationNumber) {
 int reservationNumberIndex = -1;
 for (int i = 0; i < ticketSale.length; i++) {
  if (null != ticketSale[i].getReservationNumber() && ticketSale[i].getReservationNumber().equals(reservationNumber)) {
   reservationNumberIndex = i;
   break;
  }
 }
 return reservationNumberIndex;
}
```

Best Regards,

Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

Add a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to validate that your input is a valid number `"\\d+"`:

```
   public void ticketInformation(String reservationNumber)
    {
        String regex = "\\d+";
        if(!reservationNumber.matches(regex))
        {
            System.out.println("The reservation number entered was n0t found");
        }

        int ticket = searchArray(reservationNumber);

        if(ticket == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("The reservation number entered was n0t found");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("\n" + ticketSale[ticket].toString());
        }
    }
```

You might want to validate `searchArray`, particularly if it is not used interdependently from `ticketInformation()`.